# How to edit this function so filter works when loading page with anchor (from nav menu)

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a custom filter for displaying portfolio items by category.

`Search Our Results By Sector: ALL ADVENTURE AUTO CANNABIS CONSTRUCTION EVENTS LAW OTHER RETAIL VETS`

Each of these categories has an ID, and the code I have filters all the thumbnails by the ID selected.
My issue is, I'd like to create a drop-down with all these categories as links, but they're not really links, only #ids that serve for categorizing the filter.
If I click the link:

https://www.marwickmarketing.com/testsite2019/results/#adventure

It doesn't load the page with the filtered portfolio items.
So how can I edit the code below so that when I click the sub-menu links for each category, the function works and filters my portfolio items?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    $('.thumbnail-listing .filter a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         $(".portfolio-item").removeClass("activeBlock");
        if (!$(this).hasClass("activeLink")){
            $("a").removeClass("activeLink");
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("activeLink");
        var currentHref = $(this).attr('href');

        href = currentHref.replace("#", "");
        if ($(this).hasClass("activeLink")){
            $(".portfolio-item."+href+"").addClass("activeBlock");
        }
        else{
            $(".portfolio-item."+href+"").removeClass("activeBlock");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to get the URL string and split it by the hash symbol then grab the second element (or the elements that don't have an index of 0 if you have a lot of filters ) from the resultant array that is formed by the `split()` method

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not sure how to code it up as per your suggestion. Can you please provide the code with these changes?

Comment: @user2348598 Please provide example HTML (and poss. CSS) to go with your JQuery, so we can see more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is the dev site: https://www.marwickmarketing.com/testsite2019/results/#adventure See that this link opens the Results page but the filter doesn't filter the Adventure category. How to add to my code so it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    let filter = window.location.hash; // get filter from browser
    let hashlessFilter = filter.replace("#", ""); //remove hash from filter string

     // Hide all portfolio divs
     &(".thumbnail-listing .filter a").removeClass('activeLink');
     $(".portfolio-item").removeClass("activeBlock");

    //  add active classes to the protfolio fivs matching the hash
    $(".thumbnail-listing .filter a."+hashlessFilter).addClass('activeLink');
    $(".portfolio-item."+hashlessFilter).addClass("activeBlock");


})
```

**Edit**

As per @riffnl suggestion you can skip the whole split thing and directly grab the "filter" by using the `window.location.hash` method. though you may have to deal with the hash later

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure how to implement that along with my current code... :(

Comment: @user2348598 well the current code already does most of what you want , you just have to add your filters in the for loop surrounded by if conditions, like if this then apply that filter / hide that element

Comment: I understand that it's almost there, but I'm not sure what to write. I'm beginner with scripts. Can you please help :)

Comment: @user2348598 updated to add a bit more clarity to what I meant

Comment: @user2348598 well you will have to hard code the filters or if you want you can use the filter itself to hide/ show the div by using it as the class/id name and hide the rest or the divs

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to then "hardcode" the names of the filters in this script? I was hoping to have it be dynamic, such as: load URL (e.g. "/results/#adventure", find the .portfolio-item divs with that same "adventure" class, then remove classes .activeLink and .activeBlock, and assign .activeLink to the p.filter <a href="#adventure" class="activeLink">Adventure</a> and add .activeBlock class to all .portfolio-item.adventure items. Can you provide the code that does that?

Comment: @riffnl oh, that works too. I'm used to using multiple hashes separating my filters that I instinctively suggested a split strategy, your suggestion works absolutely fine though

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you have 2 parts of a problem..

1. You want the hash of an URL to act as a search criteria
2. You want a click to not actually load a new URL (or am I mistaken?)

The first you could google quite easily.. Check for "jquery hash" or something similar...
the second is something else...

If I follow the code you posted, let's point out a few things:

1. > if (!$(this).hasClass("activeLink")){

doesn't actually matter, just remove *all* activelinks and add the activelink class to *this*, since you already know what "this" is, you couldn't care less about the rest of 'm (toggle could turn activelink off while it should be on --> that's my point)

2. Wrong values (or assumed values)

> var currentHref = $(this).attr('href');
>
> href = currentHref.replace("#", "");

you actually take the *whole* link and just replace the # part with nothing.. Meaning you have the entire rest of the url to account for in the "search criteria".. (for fun: add an "alert(href);" below that line of code).
You actually need that part, you don't want to alter it.. since you're already using jQuery I'd recommend you add a data-search (or whatever) attribute to it and add a class like 'search-' and add a

```
$('.search-' + $(this).data('search')).addClass('activeBlock');
```

or something like that..

Comment: The op wants to apply filters on page load, like sharing the link with a friend

Comment: I read the "but they're not really links" part.. and I assumed it's both (but assumption is the mother of all f-ups... true)

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply!  I'm sure this code can be done better. I'm looking to extend the function so that when someone clicks on the sub-menu (clicking menu item e.g. "/results/#adventure",) then find the .portfolio-item divs with that same "adventure" class, then remove classes .activeLink and .activeBlock, and assign .activeLink to the p.filter <a href="#adventure" class="activeLink">Adventure</a> and add .activeBlock class to all .portfolio-item.adventure items. Can you provide the code that does that?

Comment: Well I almost did that already for you...if you read my answer all the blocks to include this is already in there... Add a class to each item having your "adventure-thingy" as "seach-{adventure}" and your almost already good to go?

Comment: Appreciate it! I need a lot of hand-holding or just text ready to paste when it comes to scripts. Any chance you can edit my code so I can paste it? And then just add the search-* class to my portfolio items?